# How to deal with closely overlapping key points when using SimpleBlobDetector in OpenCV C++?

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I'm fairly new to using OpenCV with C++ and I'm currently using it to count the number of objects in a tray via blob detection.

When I use SimpleBlobDetector, I keep getting one particular key point that is basically overlapping with another already existing key point.

[image]

Why does this occur and how do I deal with it?

(Note: I only filter by area and use 500 for a minimum)

I have also included the code I used to declare the detector's parameters and also calling the detect function as well:

The images were captured using a RealSense camera which was then converted into a Mat variable for OpenCV to use.

```
//Blob Detection Setup 
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
//Area filter
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 500; //used to filter out specks
params.maxArea = 3000000; //this is just an arbitrarily very high number to exceed the default cap
//Circularity filter
params.filterByCircularity = false;
//Convexity filter
params.filterByConvexity = false;
//Inertia filter
params.filterByInertia = false;

Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> standard_detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
vector<KeyPoint> standard_keypoints;
standard_detector->detect(standard_im_inv, standard_keypoints);
int objCount = size(standard_keypoints);

Mat standard_im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints(standard_im_inv, standard_keypoints, standard_im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve the issue by changing the maximum area parameter to:

```
params.maxArea = 10000;
```

In fact, using such a huge initial max area parameter is so excessive it probably was bound to cause issues in the first place.